# Prevent SQL injection attack in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, security, sql-injection

I would like to prevent SQL attacks on this piece of PHP code (this is just a practice exercise in class). This can easily be exploited by setting `@mail` equal to something like `'); DROP TABLE PURCHASE; --`

```
$db = new SQLite3 ($db_name);

$sql = sprintf ("INSERT INTO PURCHASE (quantity, name, password, mail) 
                 VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')\n",
                 $Quantity, $Name, $Password, $Mail );

echo $sql;
if (!$db->exec ($sql)) {
    throw new Exception($db->lastErrorMsg());
}
```

I tried to prevent this by passing parameters like this, but I get `500 Internal Server Error`

```
$db = new SQLite3 ($db_name);

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO PURCHASE(quantity, name, password, mail)
            VALUES (:Quantity, :Name, :Password, :Mail)");

$sql->bindValue(':Quantity', $Quantity, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$sql->bindValue(':Name', $Name, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$sql->bindValue(':Password', $Password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$sql->bindValue(':Mail', $Mail, SQLITE3_TEXT);

echo $sql;
if (!$db->exec ($sql)) {
    throw new Exception($db->lastErrorMsg());
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SQLite3::exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php) is for executing a query string, not a prepared statement. You need to use [`SQLite3Stmt::execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) instead. Change:

```
if (!$db->exec ($sql)) {
    throw new Exception($db->lastErrorMsg());
}
```

to

```
if (!$sql->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($db->lastErrorMsg());
}
```

Note you can't `echo $sql` as it is an object, not a simple type. If you want to look at what a `SQLite3Stmt` object looks like, you would need to `print_r($sql)` or `var_dump($sql)`.